# Indexing through 'names' in a list and performing actions on contained values in R

Tags: r

I have a data set of counts from standard solutions passed through an instrument that analyses chemical concentrations (an ICPMS for those familiar).  The data is over a range of different standards and for each standard I have four repeat measurements that I want to calculate the mean and variance of.
I'm importing the data from an excel spreadsheet and then, following some housekeeping such as getting dates and times in the right format, I split the the dataset up into a list identified by the name of the standard solution using `Count11.sp<-split(Count11.raw, Count11.raw$Type)`.  Count11.raw$Type then becomes the list element name and I have the four count results for each chemical element in that list element.
So far so good.
I find I can yield an average (mean, median etc) easily enough by identifying the list element specifically i.e. `mean(Count11.sp$'Ca40')` , or `sapply(Count11$'Ca40', median)`, but what I'm not able to do is automate that in a loop so that I can calculate the means for each standard and drop that into a numerical matrix for further manipulation. I can extract the list element names with names() and I can even use a loop to make a vector of all the names and reference the specific list element using these in a for loop.
For instance `Count11.sp[names(Count11.sp[i])]`will extract the full list element no problem:

```
$`Post Ca45t`
         Type Run                Date 7Li   9Be 24Mg   43Ca 52Cr 55Mn 59Co 60Ni
77 Post Ca45t   1 2011-02-08 00:13:08 114 26101 4191 453525 2632  520  714 2270
78 Post Ca45t   2 2011-02-08 00:13:24 114 26045 4179 454299 2822  524  704 2444
79 Post Ca45t   3 2011-02-08 00:13:41  96 26372 3961 456293 2898  520  762 2244
80 Post Ca45t   4 2011-02-08 00:13:58 112 26244 3799 454702 2630  510  792 2356
   65Cu 66Zn 85Rb 86Sr 111Cd  115In 118Sn 137Ba 140Ce 141Pr 157Gd  185Re 208Pb
77  244 1036   56 3081    44 520625    78   166   724    10     0 388998   613
78  250  982   70 3103    46 526154    76   174   744    16     4 396496   644
79  246 1014   36 3183    56 524195    60   198   744     2     0 396024   612
80  270  932   60 3137    44 523366    70   180   824     2     4 390436   632
   238U
77   24
78   20
79   14
80    6
```

but `sapply(Count11.sp[names(count11.sp[i])`produces an error message: `Error in median.default(X[[i]], ...) : need numeric data`
while `sapply(Input$`Post Ca45t`, median)` <'Post Ca45t' being name Count11.sp[i] i=4> does exactly what I want and produces the median value (I can clean that vector up later for medians that don't make sense) e.g.

```
Type          Run         Date          7Li          9Be         24Mg 
      NA          2.5 1297109612.5        113.0      26172.5       4070.0 
    43Ca         52Cr         55Mn         59Co         60Ni         65Cu 
454500.5       2727.0        520.0        738.0       2313.0        248.0 
    66Zn         85Rb         86Sr        111Cd        115In        118Sn 
   998.0         58.0       3120.0         45.0     523780.5         73.0 
   137Ba        140Ce        141Pr        157Gd        185Re        208Pb 
   177.0        744.0          6.0          2.0     393230.0        622.5 
    238U 
    17.0
```

Can anyone give me any insight into how I can automate (i.e. loop through) these names to produce one median vector per list element?  I'm sure there's just some simple disconnect in my logic here that may be easily solved.

Comment: Update: I've solved the problem.  The way to do so is to use tapply on the original dataset with out the need to split it.  tapply allows functions to be applied to data based on a user defined grouping criteria.  In my case I could group according to the Count11.raw$Type and then take the mean of the data subset.  tapply(Count11.raw$Type, Count11.raw[,3:ncol(Count11.raw), mean)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've solved the problem.  The way to do so is to use tapply on the original dataset with out the need to split it.  tapply allows functions to be applied to data based on a user defined grouping criteria.  In my case I could group according to the Count11.raw$Type and then take the mean of the data subset.  `tapply(Count11.raw$Type, Count11.raw[,3:ncol(Count11.raw)], mean)`, job done.